# Power bi - measure is displaying the same value for different periods

Tags: powerbi

Thanks in advance for help.:)

Starting from the beginning i have created this table from this formulas which is developed from another table:

```
Table = 
ADDCOLUMNS (
    VALUES ( Main[Job name] ),
    "Errors", CALCULATE ( IF ( SUM ( Main[Errors] ) > 1, 0, 1 ) ),
    "Total", CALCULATE ( IF ( COUNT ( Main[Job name] ) >= 1, 1, 0 ) )
)
```

Now i want to calculate from here the following formula from the table : errors/total*100.

Which i have done it and it works but this data is also assigned to dates with this form : Thursday,May 26, 2022 .

Usually i create just a visual with the measure and date and it's automatically calculating for each month the sub-measure but for this one is the same value for all the months. It doesn't calculate for each month and just like a total.

Do you think is the table that i have created or do i have to do something different?
I also tried the slicer and that doesn't work either.

Thanks you very much for your help ! Really appreciated ! :)
If you need any info please let me know !

Update :

| Job name | Errors | Total | Date | FTR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EverCommerce, Inc. | 0 | 1 | Thursday,May 26, 2022 | 0 |
| Acutus Medical, Inc. | 1 | 1 | Thursday,June 26, 2022 | 100% |
| Gatos Silver, Inc. | 1 | 1 | Thursday,July 26, 2022 | 100% |

Please see above the table sample. I have included the date as well for reference .

What i want is below :

| Date | FTR |
| --- | --- |
| May | 0 |
| June | 100% |
| July | 100% |

I want the measure that i created (errors/total*100 ) that you can see above to be aplicable for months analysis as well so i can create later a figure . At this point when i am creating the visual with the date and measure it's giving me the same value for each month . Please see below:

| Date | FTR |
| --- | --- |
| May | 93% |
| June | 93% |
| July | 93% |

Thanks a lot for the help again !

Comment: Please share some sample data as a copyable
[markdown table](https://tableconvert.com/markdown-generator).

Comment: Hi Peter ! I just added now . Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following 2 **calculated columns** to your table:

```
Month = 'Table'[Date].[Month]
```

and

```
FTR = DIVIDE('Table'[Errors], 'Table'[Total])
```

Then you can use them in a table visual:

[image]

On a side note: The above June and July dates are not valid, since they are not on a Thursday. You have to fix that to be able to calculate the month.